# Javascript - Calculate missing 5 stars to reach desired rating

Tags: javascript, rating-system

I would like to make a script that calculate how many "5" I need to reach 4.95 rating.

I created an object:

```
var obMed = {
   5: 0,
   4: 0,
   3: 0,
   2: 0,
   1: 0
 };
```

I got this function to update previous object with my rating

```
function upOB(a,b,c,d,e) {
    obMed["5"] = a;
    obMed["4"] = b;
    obMed["3"] = c;
    obMed["2"] = d;
    obMed["1"] = e;
    return obMed;
}
```

And this function to get the rating value

```
function med(obj) {
    div = obj["5"] + obj["4"] + obj["3"] + obj["2"] + obj["1"];
    somma = (obj["5"] * 5) + (obj["4"] * 4) + (obj["3"] * 3) + (obj["2"] * 2) + (obj["1"] * 1);
    media = (somma/div).toFixed(2);
    return media;
}
```

At this point I would like to add 1 to object["5"] until my average is greater than or equal to 4.95 but I'm really stuck.

I tried loops with no results, probably I wrote them bad.

Comment: You should show your attempts to use a loop; this will help to explain where you're going wrong.

Comment: it's just simple math. you don't need a loop. you just need to figure out what "total points / number of ratings = 5.0" you need, given that your curren total/num = 4.95

Comment: Note, `media` is currently a `String`, not a `Number` after using `.toFixed()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the equations you get the following relation (using the same variable names that your code uses)

```
function getNeed(div, somma) {
  return Math.ceil((4.95*div - somma) / 0.05);
}
```

As I understand that `div` is the total amount of votes sent, and `somma` is the sum of all scores.

**Math behind the method**

current score: `somma / div`
if you add `N` votes of 5 stars, the new score would be: `(somma + N * 5) / (div + N)`
If you want that to be equal to 4.95, then you do `(somma + N * 5) / (div + N) = 4.95`, and the result is that:
`N = (4.95*div - somma) / 0.05`

Then you'll have to ceil that value as @dvsoukup commented, as you cannot have a non-integer amount of votes. This way, for example, you would have as a result 7 if the value of the computed `N` was  6.72.

Comment: you may need to take the ceiling of the result... as a result of, say, 6.72 would mean that you need "7" more five stars... you can't really have half a five star, unless you choose a 2 or 3 star. But OP is specifically asking for exactly how many "5" star ratings are needed

Comment: You're completely right. I'll update the answer with your comment

Comment: This is right, Even i tried the math. j = (( div * 4.95 ) - somma ) / 0.05

Answer (score 0):

It's a math problem.
You calculate your average in this way:

`( k1*1 + k2*2 + k3*3 + k4*4 + k5*5 ) / (k1 + k2 + k3 + k4 + k5)`

Where ***k***1..5 is the number of votes.
You want to know the number **j** of votes to reach *4.95*.

Your position is:

`( k1*1 + k2*2 + k3*3 + k4*4 + (k5+j)*5 ) / (k1 + k2 + k3 + k4 + k5+j) = 4.95`

With some math passage, that I save you, your result is:

```
j = 79*k1 + 59*k2 + 39*k3 + 19*k4 - k5
```

Apply this formula and you will get your desired number

Coming back with javascript, you have to consider:

```
var missingFives = 79*obMed[1]+59*obMed[2]+39*obMed[3]+19*obMed[4]-obMed[5];
```